# AVAudioEngine realtime frequency modulation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I would like to modify the incoming signal in realtime and send it to the iOS devices speakers. I've read that the AVAudioEngine can be used for such tasks. But can't find documentation or examples for what I would like to achieve.

For testing purposes I've done:

```
audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

let unitEffect = AVAudioUnitReverb()
unitEffect.wetDryMix = 50

audioEngine.attach(unitEffect)

audioEngine.connect(audioEngine.inputNode, to: unitEffect, format: nil)
audioEngine.connect(unitEffect, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: nil)

audioEngine.prepare()
```

and if pressing a button, I just do:

```
do {
    try audioEngine.start()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

or `audioEngine.stop()`.

The reverb effect gets applied to the signal and I can hear that it works. So now I would like to get rid of the reverb and:

1. modulate the incoming signal, for example invert the signal, modulate the frequenz etc. Is there a kind of collection of effects which can be used or the possibility to somehow mathematically modulate the frequency?
2. When launched on an iOS Device, I do get the reverb here, but the output is only on the top phone speaker not the loud bottom one. How to change that?

Answer (score 2):

This github repository literally made it: https://github.com/dave234/AppleAudioUnit.

Just add `BufferedAudioUnit` to your project from there and subclass it with your implementation like this:

AudioProcessingUnit.h:

```
#import "BufferedAudioUnit.h"

@interface AudioProcessingUnit : BufferedAudioUnit

@end
```

AudioProcessingUnit.m:

```
#import "AudioProcessingUnit.h"

@implementation AudioProcessingUnit

-(ProcessEventsBlock)processEventsBlock:(AVAudioFormat *)format {

    return ^(AudioBufferList       *inBuffer,
             AudioBufferList       *outBuffer,
             const AudioTimeStamp  *timestamp,
             AVAudioFrameCount     frameCount,
             const AURenderEvent   *realtimeEventListHead) {

        for (int i = 0; i < inBuffer->mNumberBuffers; i++) {

            float *buffer = inBuffer->mBuffers[i].mData;
            for (int j = 0; j < inBuffer->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize; j++) {
                buffer[j] = /*process it here*/;
            }

            memcpy(outBuffer->mBuffers[i].mData, inBuffer->mBuffers[i].mData, inBuffer->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize);
        }
    };
}

@end
```

And, in your AVAudioEngine setup:

```
let audioComponentDescription = AudioComponentDescription(
            componentType: kAudioUnitType_Effect,
            componentSubType: kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO,
            componentManufacturer: 0x0,
            componentFlags: 0,
            componentFlagsMask: 0
        );

        AUAudioUnit.registerSubclass(
            AudioProcessingUnit.self,
            as: audioComponentDescription,
            name: "AudioProcessingUnit",
            version: 1
        )

        AVAudioUnit.instantiate(
            with: audioComponentDescription,
            options: .init(rawValue: 0)
        ) { (audioUnit, error) in
            guard let audioUnit = audioUnit else {
                NSLog("Audio unit is NULL")
                return
            }

            let formatHardwareInput = self.engine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)

            self.engine.attach(audioUnit)
            self.engine.connect(
                self.engine.inputNode,
                to: audioUnit,
                format: formatHardwareInput
            )
            self.engine.connect(
                audioUnit,
                to: self.engine.outputNode,
                format: formatHardwareInput
            )
        }
```